# Woocommerce section name?

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, theme-customizer

[image]

What is the customizer section name? I want to add a field option under customizer woocommerce section. Or how will I add a field under woocommerce option? Can someone help me with that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WOO custmizer settings are under 'woocommerce' customizer panel ( panel has been added since WP 4.0)

```
add_action('customize_register',"SE_add_options_t_woo_customizer");

function SE_add_options_t_woo_customizer($wp_customize ){
  $wp_customize->add_section( "my_new_section" , 
    array(
      'title' => "My new section",
      'priority' => 20,
      'panel' => 'woocommerce', // here is where you grab the woocommerce panel to add settings and controls to
      ) 
    );
  $wp_customize->add_setting('my_new_setting',
     array(
        'default'              => 'no',
        'type'                 => 'option',
        'capability'           => 'manage_woocommerce',
        'sanitize_callback'    => 'wc_bool_to_string',
        'sanitize_js_callback' => 'wc_string_to_bool',
    )
  );
  $wp_customize->add_control('my_new_control',
    array(
        'label'       => __( 'Control', 'woocommerce' ),
        'description' => __( 'This is my new control', 'woocommerce' ),
        'section'     => 'my_new_section',
        'settings'    => 'my_new_setting',
        'type'        => 'checkbox',
    )
);

}
```